# Slow inner join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have Oracle database with a main table contain 9 000 000 rows and a second with 19 000 000 rows.

When I do :

```
SELECT *
FROM main m
INNER JOIN second s ON m.id = s.fk_id AND s.cd = 'E' AND s.line = 1
```

It's take 45 seconds to get the first part of the result, even with all the index below :

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_1 ON SECOND (LINE, CD, FK_ID, ID);
CREATE INDEX IDX_1 ON SECOND (LINE, CD);
MAIN (ID) AS PRIMARY KEY
```

Any idea how to do it faster ? I try some index, rebuild but it's always take 45 seconds

Here is the execution plan :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name                 | Rows    | Bytes      | Cost   | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                      | 8850631 | 2133002071 | 696494 | 00:00:28 |
| * 1 |   HASH JOIN          |                      | 8850631 | 2133002071 | 696494 | 00:00:28 |
| * 2 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | SECOND               | 8850631 |  646096063 | 143512 | 00:00:06 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | MAIN                 | 9227624 | 1550240832 | 153363 | 00:00:06 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 1 - access("M"."ID"="S"."FK_ID")
* 2 - filter("S"."CD"='D' AND "S"."LINE"=1)
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for your data to add a unique(or primary) key for those four columns rather than this current index ? If possible, probably you'll able to get a performance gain.

Comment: Post the query plan.  How selective are your predicates?

Comment: Well if only one table is indexed, you will have to `full table scan` the other - this explaind our 45 seconds. If you want to see the **first record fast**  you must have index on `second` table to access `s.cd = 'E' AND s.line = 1` and  index on `main` to access on the join columns. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) the additional information you should provide.

Comment: *Important to know* - how many rows match the predicate `s.cd = 'E' AND s.line = 1`? How many rows do you expect the join will return?

Comment: Looks to me that `fk_id` is more selective than the other columns; if that's the case, then it should be placed first in the index, as in: `second (fk_id, cd, line)`.

Comment: @TheImpaler - this index  will not help much with the predicate `s.cd = 'E' AND s.line = 1` (other than with some `Index Skip Scan` access that will not help too much if there are lot of `line`s).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Unfortunately I agree.

Comment: If `fk_id` is first in the index then you would be relying on join condition to obtain the value you're driving the index. This will be every different value in `main`.`id` (there's no filters on `main`), this looks like a foreign key relation so you will end up reading all over the index to cover every single possible value of `second`.`fk_id`. This will be slower than just using the equality conditions that exist against the existing first two columns of the index - these will allow only the part of the index that matches those filters to be read - most likely a lot less than the alternative

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see *the first line quickly* you have to enable Oracle to use the `NESTED LOOP` join.

This will required an index on `second` with the two columns you constraint in your query and an index on `main` on the join column `id`

```
create index second_idx on second(line,cd);
create index main_idx on main(id);
```

You'll see an execution plan similar to one below

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |    87 |  8178 |   178   (0)| 00:00:03 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                 |            |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |            |    87 |  8178 |   178   (0)| 00:00:03 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| SECOND     |    87 |  2523 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SECOND_IDX |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | MAIN_IDX   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | MAIN       |     1 |    65 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - access("S"."LINE"=1 AND "S"."CD"='E')
   5 - access("M"."ID"="S"."FK_ID")
```

You will access via index all rows in `second` with requested `line`and `cd` (plan line 4 and 3) and for each such row you'll access via index the `main` table  (lines 5 and 6)

This will **provide an instant access to the first few rows** and will work fine if there are a low number of rows in `second` table with the selected line and cd. In other case (when there is a large number of rows with `s.cd = 'E' AND s.line = 1` - say 10k+) you will still see the first result rows quickly, but you'll *wait ages* to see the **last** row (it will take much more that the 45 seconds to *finish* the query).

If this is a problem you have to use a `HASH JOIN` (which you probaly do now).

A hash join *typically* doesn not use indexes and produced following execution  plan

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |        | 10182 |  1153K|   908   (1)| 00:00:11 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |        | 10182 |  1153K|   908   (1)| 00:00:11 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| SECOND | 10182 |    99K|   520   (2)| 00:00:07 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MAIN   | 90000 |  9316K|   387   (1)| 00:00:05 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - access("M"."ID"="S"."FK_ID")
   2 - filter("S"."LINE"=1 AND "S"."CD"='E')
```

**Summary**

To use the `nested loops` the indexes must be available as described above

The switch between `nested loops`and `hash join` is done by the Oracle database (CBO) - provided that your tables statistics and database configuration are fine.

Comment: Thanks, the result of the query return 9 229 434 rows. I add the execution plan to the main question. I can't create the 2 index of specified because colums are already indexed..

Comment: @Bosshoss to join 8.8 M rows from `second` with a 9.2 M rows from `main` the `hash join` with `full  table scan` (as in your posted execution plan) is the  preferable option. You can speed up a bit using the *parallel* option.